# Pandas Interpolate on Resample Returning NAs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to resample and interpolate between time series data. For some reason, I keep getting rows of NAs.

```
import pandas as pd

track = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': [32.743680275092686, 32.75168725999735,
                                   32.7782220355535, 32.783715199616,
                                   32.78683419954979, 32.80517578125,
                                   32.809039616988876, 32.82146906448623,
                                   32.83804166114936, 32.839903750662074],
                     'longitude': [-111.19133774115113, -111.205463020169,
                                   -111.25232307278381, -111.26207624162947,
                                   -111.26762545838648, -111.30013602120536,
                                   -111.30697444993622, -111.32877894810267,
                                   -111.35798240194515, -111.36134556361606],
                     'altitude':  [21125.0, 20975.0,
                                   20175.0, 20000.0,
                                   19900.0, 19350.0,
                                   19225.0, 18850.0,
                                   18325.0, 18250.0]},
                  index=[pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:57:24.189484'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:57:32.102171'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:57:58.872157'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:58:04.522744'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:58:07.806292'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:58:26.574050'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:58:30.495372'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:58:43.221657'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:59:00.496501'),
                         pd.Timestamp('2016-10-20 20:59:02.362993')])

track.resample('S').interpolate('linear')
```

The resampled and interpolated result is filled entirely with NaNs:

```
                     latitude  longitude  altitude
2016-10-20 20:57:24       NaN        NaN       NaN
2016-10-20 20:57:25       NaN        NaN       NaN
2016-10-20 20:57:26       NaN        NaN       NaN
2016-10-20 20:57:27       NaN        NaN       NaN
2016-10-20 20:57:28       NaN        NaN       NaN
...
```

I suspect that there is a complication with wanting to take points that have millisecond resolution and interpolate on 1-second bounds between them. I can round the index to the nearest second and get a result closer to what I'd expect:

```
track.index = track.index.round('1s')
track.resample('S').interpolate('linear')
```

Result:

```
                      latitude   longitude      altitude
2016-10-20 20:57:24  32.743680 -111.191338  21125.000000
2016-10-20 20:57:25  32.744681 -111.193103  21106.250000
2016-10-20 20:57:26  32.745682 -111.194869  21087.500000
2016-10-20 20:57:27  32.746683 -111.196635  21068.750000
2016-10-20 20:57:28  32.747684 -111.198400  21050.000000
...
```

Rounding introduces some degree of error, albeit small in this particular case. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what errors in 2nd method. All NA result in first method is expected because first it takes snapshot at 00 seconds and gets NA value so it is interpolating between all na values.

Comment: Rounding moves a sample that actually occured at 15.5 seconds to simply appear to be a sample at 16 seconds. I guess I was hoping that it would be able to linearly interpret to a value at 16 seconds rather than simply using the one from 15.5.